# Un-defined behavior when using hex values without Casting

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, chess

This is the strangest problem I have ever encountered. I am programming a chess engine and I have a function that returns a rank mask. For example, Consider this 64-bit bitboard.

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000100
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

The `1` in the middle is a piece.

Now my function should return

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
11111111
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

Very simple, just return a mask of the rank. Here is my code

```cpp
uint64_t get_rank_mask(int sq)
{
    return (0xFF<<(sq-(sq%8)));
}
```

Here is what the function returns when I pass **36**, or the square **e5**

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
11111111
```

Hmm, strange it is. Let me make a small change in the code.

```cpp
uint64_t get_rank_mask(int sq)
{
    uint64_t mask = 0xFF;
    mask<<=(sq-(sq%8));
    return  mask;
}
```

Here is the return value now

```
00000000
00000000
00000000
11111111
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

And magically, that is the intended result. I don't even know the difference between the two code samples. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Comment: `return (0xFF<<(sq-(sq%8)));` common type is `int`; `mask<<=(sq-(sq%8));` common type is `uint64_t`

Comment: @RichardCritten Except `<<` and `<<=` don't use the common type. They just use the left operand type (which is still the issue).

Comment: what you want is `0xFFull`

Comment: @Yamahari I am using `static_cast<uint64_t>(foo);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0xFF` is an `int`. Assuming an `int` has 32 bits, shifting this value left by 32 will invoke undefined behavior.

In the second version, you are storing `0xFF` in an unsigned integral type. This can be shifted any number of bits, and that operation is well defined. In your case, you are storing it in an unsigned int with 64 bits, and so shifting left by 32 gives the result you want.

Comment: @cigien How do I convert `0xFF` to a 64-bit integer without creating a new variable ?

Comment: @AryanParekh You can `static_cast<uint64_t>(0xff)`

Comment: Can't it be `0xffULL`?

Comment: @stark I think `unsigned long long` doesn't guarantee the number of bits always but `uint64_t` does

Comment: @AryanParekh -- `unsigned long long` is required to be at least 64 bits wide. If it's larger than that it will still work just fine.